# Add padding to bitmap programmatically

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

It seems, that if image, that is used for icon for Windows shortcuts, doesn't have aspect ratio 1:1, it will look stretched.

[image]

Left one is how it actually looks, and right one is how it should look.

I'm creating shortcut and icon programmatically from image, so I want to fix image, so it will have correct aspect ratio, but image will not look stretched. This can be achieved by adding some padding to image.

As for now, I'm simply copying image to new bitmap with correct aspect ratio, but filling new area with transparent pixels

```
public static Bitmap FixBitmapAspectRatio(Bitmap sourceBitmap)
{
    if (sourceBitmap.Width.Equals(sourceBitmap.Height))
        return sourceBitmap;

    int size;
    bool horizontallyOriented;
    if (sourceBitmap.Width > sourceBitmap.Height)
    {
        horizontallyOriented = true;
        size = sourceBitmap.Width;
    }
    else
    {
        horizontallyOriented = false;
        size = sourceBitmap.Height;
    }

    var sizeDifference = Math.Abs(sourceBitmap.Width - sourceBitmap.Height);

    var newBitmap = new Bitmap(size, size);

    var transparentColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (horizontallyOriented)
            {
                if (i < sizeDifference / 2 || i >= sizeDifference / 2 + sourceBitmap.Height)
                {
                    newBitmap.SetPixel(j, i, transparentColor);
                }
                else
                {
                    var originalPixel = sourceBitmap.GetPixel(j, i - sizeDifference / 2);
                    newBitmap.SetPixel(j, i, originalPixel);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (i < sizeDifference / 2 || i >= sizeDifference / 2 + sourceBitmap.Width)
                {
                    newBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, transparentColor);
                }
                else
                {
                    var originalPixel = sourceBitmap.GetPixel(i - sizeDifference / 2, j);
                    newBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, originalPixel);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return newBitmap;
}
```

But I don't know, if I'm inventing a wheel. Is there any way to do this by means by standard libraries, or maybe easier way to achieve what I need?

Comment: *"This can be achieved by adding some padding to image"* - bad idea to fix original problem, which is probably a mistake in your code creating icon from image. Do you still want to get answers to your question or do you want to fix problem? If latter - show how you creating icons.

Comment: @Sinatr you can just draw any image with aspect ratio different from 1:1 (e.g. red rectangle 64x32), convert it to icon by any means (e.g. using [this site](http://converticon.com)), and make any shortcut to use this icon. You will see the problem (shortcut will have red square icon, not rectangle). I heavily doubt it is problem of my icon creation.

Comment: As for converting bitmap to image, I'm using method specified [here](https://gist.github.com/darkfall/1656050)

Comment: *"input image with width = height is suggested to get the best result*" - that code obviously doesn't deal with different ratio (it produces result, but result is, as you have realized, not the best).

Comment: First at all, as I've mentioned, just try to create icon with different aspect ratio by any means, and check how it looks. Anyway, what do you think my real problem is? On input, I have image with custom aspect rate, and that can't be changed. I need to make icon with that image. As I've specified, for now I deal with this problem by fixing its aspect ratio by setting padding. If you think, that actual problem is icon conversion, and you have better method of creating icons, which will work perfect with custom aspect ratio as well, please, share it. I will be glad to mark it as correct answer.

Comment: See @Luaan answer please. You can utilize GDI+ to create bitmap of required size, then scale image (keeping it aspect ratio) and then draw it at calculated position. That will produce result you expect.

Comment: Ah, ok, so, it works this way as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't want to set individual pixels :)

Instead, have a look at the `Graphics` class, in particular `Graphics.FromImage` (that's where you paint to) and `Graphics.DrawImage` (that's how you paint the scaled image).

Comment: Isn't that for drawing image on screen? Did you read full text of question? I'm creating icons physically, as files on drive. Only then I can use them for shortcut.